# Change sorting of WooCommerce My account customer orders

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce, customers can log in to their account and see the order history. By default the orders are displaying with the newest order date first.

I want to turn this around, so the order with the oldest date shows first.

I can't find any place to change ordering from ASC/DESC, looking in the template file `woocoommerce/myaccount/orders.php` file.

```
<table class="woocommerce-orders-table woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ( $customer_orders->orders as $customer_order ) :
```

Any way to alter the loop to display orders with the oldest date first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter hook `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query` allows to change the `'order'` argument to `ASC` (ascending), changing the sorting behavior on My account customer orders list:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'my_account_orders_query_change_sorting' );
function my_account_orders_query_change_sorting( $args ) {
    $args['order'] = 'ASC'; // Default is 'DESC'

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: If I want to give option to user by selecting option from dropdown so how can I implement that?
I tried more to do that but I am not getting completing it.