# Change sorting of WooCommerce customer orders --> orders.php

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, sql-order-by, orders

In WooCommerce, customers can log in to their account and see the order history. By default the orders are displaying with the newest order date first.

I want to show the unpaid orders before, the paid orders. So customers can find the unpaid orders directly when they open their order history.

I can't find any place to change ordering from ASC/DESC, looking in the template file woocoommerce/myaccount/orders.php file.

Comment: Referring to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270594/change-sorting-of-woocommerce-my-account-customer-orders/61822779#61822779

Comment: I can't figure out how to order by meta_key.

{
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'my_account_orders_query_change_sorting' );
function my_account_orders_query_change_sorting( $args ) {
  $args = array(
  'meta_key' => 'post_status',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'DESC'
 );
 
    return $args;
}}

Comment: @LoicTheAztec It's not the same question, it's just familiar. My question is about ordering by meta data